# F# and OpenTK in Windows Forms

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, opentk

Does anyone know a good tutorial of using F# and OpenTK in Windows Forms?

These links I've already seen:
http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/releases/view/55463
http://www.opentk.com/node/1889

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I believe the examples in the [fsxplat](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/) project should be a decent starting point. There are two ways you can use OpenTK with WinForms.

- If you're creating an application that has just one OpenTK window, then you can inherit from `GameWindow` and implement your logic in `OnRenderFrame`. Then you just create an instance of your object and call `Run`. This approach is used for example in the [cube tutorial](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3dbd89b23e34#samples/opengl/cube.fs).
- If you want to use OpenTK as part of a larger application, you can create a standard `Form` and add `GLControl` (from `OpenTK.GLControl.dll`), which is a standard WinForms control that renders content using OpenTK. You can find an example [in `DrawingForm` type here](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3dbd89b23e34#samples/opengl/functional3d/functional3d.fs).